# Angular 7 - Custom library - build Error during template compile of 'Injectable'

Tags: typescript, build, angular7

I have a Angular 7.1 based custom library project which uses supporting libraries like rxjs 6.4 etc. My TypeScript version is "typescript": "^3.1.6" and I have made sure to modify all the imports and also the other related changes. Still while doing 
ng build
or 
ng build abccustom-lib
I see this error
[image]
[image]

So with these 2 errors (in multiple times) I am kind of stuck at this point. Have tried several solutions. I do not want to install rxjs-compat. But I dont think this issue is due to the lack of rxjs-compat.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `[workspace]/projects/abccustom-lib/node_modules` directory for the presence of `@angular/common` and/or `@angular/core`.

If either of them are present, delete them, and then check the `[workspace]/projects/abccustom-lib/package.json` file to ensure that they are included only as `peerDependancies`.  They should not appear under `dependancies` or `devDependancies` at all, so if they have found their way into either of those, remove them.

If your problem was the same as mine, you should now be able to run `ng build abccustom-lib` without issues.